# How to bind one texblock value to other textblock one way and get value in MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, xaml-binding

Let me explain my question by an Image [image]

I have MVVM structure in My project.
I have two textblocks, `Textblock 1` and `textblock 2`. Now I want `textblock2's` Text same as `Textblock1's` Text, whenever Textblock1's Text changed.
but I should be able to set `Textblock2's` Text different from `Textblock1's`.
So I am setting Oneway binding of Textblock1's Text Property.

How Can I get the Text property of `Textblock2's` In MVVM. If I create a property for `Textblock2's` Text property, I wont be able to bind `Textblock1's` text to `textblock2`.

Let me know if I want to clear my question further.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

Use two properties in VM, and implement the equal/override logic there. That's exactly the kind of stuff VMs are good in.

```
VM 
  Prop1 <-- Binding- TextBlock1
  Prop2 <-- Binding- TextBlock2
```

The Prop1 setter is implemented such that it also updates Prop2 (don't forget INotifyPropertyChanged), if you set Prop2 make it to switch to and keep the different value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply flq, Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: In Textblock I have binded a property from a class object. So if other fields of class changed it changes prop2.
So In case I change textblock1's content (ie. cont1) and then textblock2 (ie. cont2), and I change other prop binded with class object, I get textblock2 also changed to "cont1"

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to go along with flq's answer:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _text1;
    private string _text2;

    public string Text1
    {
        get { return _text1; }
        set
        {
            if (_text1 != value)
            {
                _text1 = value;                    

                RaisePropertyChanged("Text1");

                Text2 = _text1;
            }
        }
    }        

    public string Text2
    {
        get { return _text2; }
        set
        {
            if (_text2 != value)
            {
                _text2 = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Text2");
            }
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {

    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }        
}
```

Be sure to change your bindings to two-way.

EDIT:

Here is the XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text2}" />
```

Setting UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged allows the property to be updated as you type, so TextBox2 will update as you type. (FYI - The default bindings for TextBoxes is Two-Way)